# How to count points laying above and below the identity line (x = y) in an R plot

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to count the number of points laying below and above the identity line (x = y) in a plot.

```
plot(datatumor$ageChronologique, datatumor$ageMethylation, 
     xlab ="Chronological age", ylab= "DNAm age")
abline(0,1)
```

"ageChronologique" and "ageMethylation" are two measurement variables of datatumor.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could combine the logical `datatumor$ageChronologique < datatumor$ageMethylation` with `sum`:

```
# above 45 degree line:
sum(datatumor$ageChronologique < datatumor$ageMethylation)
# below 45 degree line:
sum(datatumor$ageChronologique > datatumor$ageMethylation)
```

Maybe it looks a little nicer using `with`:

```
# above 45 degree line:
with(datatumor, sum(ageChronologique < ageMethylation))
```

If you have missing values (NAs) in your variables, you can include the na.rm=T argument in `sum` to ignore these:

```
sum(datatumor$ageChronologique > datatumor$ageMethylation, na.rm=T)
```

Comment: It gives me NA in both cases although I see may points that fall above and below the line.

Comment: You  have missing values in your variables. I'll edit my answer to account for this.